# Eclipse run configuration annoyance

Tags: eclipse, jar

If I run a jar as follows
`java -jar Name.jar arg1 arg2 arg3`
it is understandable that when exporting (creating the .jar) I would have had to specify an Eclipse run configuration in order to identify the main method because there may be as many main methods as there are classes.

If I run a main program from within Eclipse, it silently creates a new run configuration which adds more clutter to the run configuration choices available when I want to export. If I do this for many classes, the chances are I have many essentially identical run configurations, with the only difference being the main method specified.

If I run a jar as follows

`java -cp Name.jar package.MyObject arg1 arg2`

`java -cp Name.jar package.MyOtherObject arg1`

then the Eclipse run configuration which identifies the main method is probably ignored. The entry point is identified on the command line. In this case, the fact that Eclipse requires a run configuration during the export process, seems to create a chore, but there seems to be no way to avoid this.

I prefer to run my .jar via the `-cp` option because it gives me access to many entry points. This way I don't have to re-export when I want to access a different entry point. The decision as to which entry point to use is postponed until the time I want to run. I don't have to decide when exporting. I preserve flexibility.

I know an alternative way is to just have an `arg1` that specifies the task, so I can rely on just one run configuration that identifies the main method that has a big switch statement and then always invoke Java with the `-jar` option.

If I use `-jar` there is the clutter of many run configurations. If I use `-cp` there seems to be an nuisance step in the export process that involves the clutter of many run configurations. Is there a way to use Eclipse that avoids both of these problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open the project and select `File` and `Export` and `Java` and `JAR file`. Do not select `Runnable JAR file`.
2. By default, every file in the project folder is check-boxed as a resource meant to be exported and you may want to un-check some or all of them. Unfortunately Eclipse does not remember this so you may have to un-check resources every time you are exporting.
3. Check-box the `src` directory which unfortunately makes it appear you want to export source but actually you need to check-box it in order to export the corresponding `.class` files.
4. Check-box `Export generated class files and resources`.
5. Browse to the destination JAR file that you want to export or overwrite.
6. Click `finish`.
7. Eclipse does not consider third-party JAR files to be resources in the above step 2 so you need to find a way to provide them to the `-classpath` or `-cp` when you invoke Java. The reason we need to do this is because when Eclipse exports a "JAR file" it doesn't seem to follow the build paths to your third-party JAR files. This is a capability that Eclipse has when it exports a "Runnable JAR file" but that's not what we are doing here. You can manually create a directory of your third-party JAR files and let Java expand a wildcard in `-classpath`.

Example Java invocation in linux:

`java -cp ~/directory/destination.jar:/home/username/directory/thirdparty/"*" com.domain.package.MyObject arg1 arg2 arg3`

Note that on linux we can allow bash to expand the `~` for your own JAR file, "destination.jar". For the third-party JAR files the long form `/home/username` is used because tilde expansion might not work in the middle of the string, just after the colon.

If we want to use the Java `*` wildcard -- not the same thing as the bash command line wildcard -- for the third-party JAR files, the `*` character must be quoted (made literal) in order for the wildcard to be passed to Java.

Exporting this way eliminates the need to select a run configuration and addresses the concern that prompted the question.

Aside: If your own JAR is exported to the same directory as the third-party JARs then classpath is simpler:

`java -cp ~/singleDirectory/"*" com.domain.package.MyObject arg1 arg2 arg3`